# SSH login without password fail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I follow this [post](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to do SSH login without password, it works for a while, but now I can not automatically login.

```
ssh -v -p 10022 leo@cassandra

Error:
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cassandra [172.18.101.112] port 10022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/leo/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 57:8a:49:c6:88:90:f8:b0:94:c5:f9:eb:2f:34:9e:76
debug1: Host '[cassandra]:10022' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/leo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password


My PC:
drwx------  2 leo leo  4096 May  7 19:56 .ssh
-rw-------  1 leo leo 1766 May  7 19:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 leo leo  444 May  7 19:56 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--  1 leo leo  407 May  7 19:55 id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDIu4NxzrlOgv4P82cw6u4PokzRWcWlx31n2BBuYg1KU0QLfqe5kCeJabN405qhwRzZjUCxbWeRvWVUPcnnNKgpj0+2wJtW4Bjt0HjWWj+R6gNxdrQQeioOBynopeIPKBzKcwnzBcbHKQQWEKTWFb+MFDF9EOK0sliD2Dsdm
p87IjKe24/jmNRX+7tCeux0whnFWsbfjOhZ4AGzGWTAHWY2gdVSH3T4hCY4e/BRf7VSCLV9ijyzcI6e82ZuXlZCCIGg/maP6QV1CXhpbQKtui07Lm8GcrUwwn8KYZEKHSMZTmBpVIeryKtmtrQ0SfT5tlOQ1g5IzQRryjxZvqOH597/ leo@kai-PC

Remote:
drwxrwxr-x 2 leo leo  4096 May  7 19:59 .ssh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leo leo  407 May  7 19:59 authorized_keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDIu4NxzrlOgv4P82cw6u4PokzRWcWlx31n2BBuYg1KU0QLfqe5kCeJabN405qhwRzZjUCxbWeRvWVUPcnnNKgpj0+2wJtW4Bjt0HjWWj+R6gNxdrQQeioOBynopeIPKBzKcwnzBcbHKQQWEKTWFb+MFDF9EOK0sliD2Dsdm
p87IjKe24/jmNRX+7tCeux0whnFWsbfjOhZ4AGzGWTAHWY2gdVSH3T4hCY4e/BRf7VSCLV9ijyzcI6e82ZuXlZCCIGg/maP6QV1CXhpbQKtui07Lm8GcrUwwn8KYZEKHSMZTmBpVIeryKtmtrQ0SfT5tlOQ1g5IzQRryjxZvqOH597/ leo@kai-PC
```

I am not familiar with ssh's authentication protocol, anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From your output, the remote machine has write permission for the group on the .ssh directory.

You need to remove write permission from the .ssh directory and home directory for anyone other than the owner on the remote machine, as advised at e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/54670/passwordless-ssh-not-working